# Pylint error __init__ method from base class '*' is not called

Tags: python, python-2.x, pylint

I have an pylint error:

`__init__ method from base class 'night' is not called`

I have a file called day_night.py:

```
// is_it_night returns True False depending on the time
import is_it_night

class Day():

   def __init__(self):
       // dosomething

class Night():

    def __init__(self):
        // dosomethingdifferent   
what_time = Day

if is_it_night():
    what_time = Night
```

Now I have a class called instance.py which looks like this:

```
from day_night import what_time

class instance(day_night):

   def __init__(self):
      what_time.__init__(self)
```

And now I get the pylint error on incstance.py that

```
 __init__ method from base class 'night' is not called
```

How do I fix this, I tried super but that creates other problems

if i do instance.py

```
from day_night import what_time

class instance(day_night):

   def __init__(self):
      super(instance, self).__init__(self)
```

I get the following error: use super on old style class

And I would prefer not to do # pylint: disable=

Comment: `__init` != `__init__`. Besides, if you use `super` correctly, it does not create other problems. Show us your code using `super`

Comment: Could you fix the indentation, comments, typos etc? In other words, please show us your actual code and not some vague approximation.

Comment: You are also using "self" as a base class. Suggest that you fix your code example so that it run.

Comment: If you do `from day_night import what_time`, your base class is `what_time` and you should inherit from that. And you should call `__init__` from your own `__init__`, not from the class initializer (it makes no sense).

Comment: @NPE This is code derevid from actaul code, should have read it first before submitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to do something in Day/Night initialization from instance.py.

Change code in instance.py to:

```
from day_night import what_time

class myInstance(what_time):
    pass
    # do something, other than defining a __init__() function
m = myInstance()
```

If you don't define a `__init__()` in subclass, when it's instancing, `__init__()` from baseclass will be invoked.

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Now I get the error:  __init__ method from base class 'night' is not called and  __init__ method from base class 'day' is not called

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be

```
from day_night import what_time

class instance(day_night):
   what_time.__init__(self)
```

Here

```
from day_night import what_time
```

you import the class `what_time`, and from this you should derive.

So do

```
class instance(what_time): # instance is wrongly named...
    def __init__(self):
        super(instance, self).__init__() # here you do the requested call
```

or, if you cannot change your classes to new.style classes for some reason (just derive from `object` additionally), you can do

```
class instance(what_time): # instance is wrongly named...
    def __init__(self):
        what_time.__init__(self) # here you do the requested call
```

Or, as m170897017 suggests, omit the `__init__` altogether:

```
class instance(what_time): # instance is wrongly named...
    pass
```